# How to make sendmail to relay local mails?

Tags: linux, sendmail, user-accounts

I have www server called say mywebsite.com and mail serwer mymail.com. Mail for mywebsite.com is handled by mymail.com (mx record for mywebsite.com is mymail.com). Problem is that I want to send mails from my www server mywebsite.com to adress in domain mywebsite.com.

So I configured sendmail on mywebsite.com to relay all mails via mymail.com. 
i change sendmail config on mywebsite.com:
`dnl # define('SMART_HOST', 'mymail.com')dnl`

Problem is that sendmail complains when im sending to for example rafal@mywebsite.com that user is unkown (but that mailbox exist on mymail.com). All maibloxes are on mymail.com not on mywebsite.com.

this is log from telnet to localhost on mywebsite.com

```
root@mywebsite.com# telnet localhost 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1).
Escape character is '^]'.
220 familie.pl ESMTP Sendmail 8.13.8/8.13.8; Sun, 6 Nov 2011 18:21:04 +0100
helo domain.pl
250 domain.pl Hello localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you
mail from: me@mywebsite.com
250 2.1.0 me@mywebsite.com... Sender ok
rcpt to: rafal@mywebsite.com
550 5.1.1 rafal@website.com ... User unknown
data
503 5.0.0 Need RCPT (recipient)
```

Is there a way to disable checking rcpt for local domain??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is cited from http://www.tipstrs.com/tip/13296/Setting-up-sendmail-with-a-catch-all-for-unknown-email-addresses

---

If you're running sendmail on a Linux server, it's quite easy to configure sendmail so that any email sent to an unknown email address in your domain is forwarded to a known address. Doing this results in getting a bunch more spam, but I like this cause I can then use email addresses that don't exist for specific purposes (such as when a forum requires a valid email address as part of the sign-up confirmation process).

Here's how to set up an catch-all for all unknown email addresses in Fedora (your disto may be slightly different), all of these commands need to be run under the root user:

1. Edit the `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc` file and look for the line that contains virtusertable in it and make sure it is not commented out. If it is commented out, remove the comment. In my case, it looks like this:

   ```
   FEATURE(`virtusertable', `hash -o /etc/mail/virtusertable.db')dn
   ```
2. Edit the `/etc/mail/virtusertable` file and add lines like the following, one for each domain on your server that you want to add a catch-all for:

   ```
   @domain1.com postmaster-domain1
   @domain2.com postmaster-domain2
   ```

   In this example, any mail sent to an unknown user at domain1.com will be forwarded to the postmaster-domain1 user, and any email sent to an unknown user at domain2.com will be forwarded to the postmaster-domain2 user. For this to work, the users to whom the mail is being forwarded must exist, and be able to receive mail.
3. From the `/etc/mail` directory, run the `make` command.
4. Restart the sendmail service using the `service sendmail restart` command.

That's all there is to it. Once you take this few simple steps you wil  l have a catch-all for any email sent to unknown users in your domain.

Comment: this isnt what im looking for... a want to disable checking rcpt to because i have mailboxes @mywebsite.com on my mail server mymail.com and web aplication from mywebsite.com want to sent mails there. But sendmail is checking if this mailboxes are on mywebsite.com before he relay them to mymail.com.

Comment: @B14D3 So then you misconfigured your local Sendmail as being responsible for `mywebsite.com`. Remove that.