# Redirect all mails to local account during development

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I'm developing a webshop. When a order has been placed it sends out invoices and notifications to coworkers via email. Developing anything related to the emails has become really annoying, as I have to change a lot of code during development to avoid sending my coworkers random mails.

I'm using PHP's `mail` function with the sendmail backend. What I would like to do is configure sendmail to send all mails to my own account instead of the actual addressee.
That way I wouldn't have to change any code when I move to production where sendmail is configured differently.

In short: Is there a simple way to redirect outgoing emails during development?

Comment: Sounds like a sendmail question, which is off-topic for this site. Perhaps http://unix.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Probably a sendmail question yeah, though I'm interested how other developers test sending emails. I would install anything that solves this easily too.

Comment: I define email addresses as a configuration item and maintain different configurations for development and production environments.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make sendmail to relay local mails?](http://serverfault.com/questions/328294/how-to-make-sendmail-to-relay-local-mails)

Answer (score 2):

Proper way: tune your sendmail.

Fun way: all your php script does is sending mail text and headers to bash script or binary set in php.ini `sendmail_path`. You can put there your own script, which will do with you mail whatever you want.

Or you can put nothing to `sendmail_path` and set some `mail.log`. You will see, that scripts use mail properly, but mail won't actualy work.

Answer (score 0):

Append at your sendmail.mc:

```
LOCAL_RULE_2
R$+ < @ $=w . > $*     username < @ example.com. >
```

The two sides of the expression are not separated by many spaces but by a TAB